# Class Confusion, Writing a Stack Simulator

Tags: java, oop

I am having some serious problems trying to implement a simple object oriented program. I have a stack class defined as follows...

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class stack
    {
        // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
        private int maxStack;
        private int emptyStack;
        private int top;
        private int[] stack;


        public stack(int size)
        {        
            maxStack = size;
            emptyStack = -1;
            top = emptyStack;
            stack = new int[maxStack];
        }

        public int push(int y)
        {
            top++;
            stack[top]= y;
            return 0;
        }

        public int pull(int y){
            int temp = top;
            top--;
            return stack[temp];    
        }

        public boolean isEmpty(){
            return top == emptyStack;
        }

        public void print(){
            for(int i =top;i<0;i--){
                System.out.println("Position "+top+" "+stack[top]);
            }

        }

    }

I am trying to reference this class from another class that I am calling...


     import java.io.*;

     public class stackTest
      {

       public void stackStarter(){

            System.out.println("Welcome to our Stack Simulator");
            InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(ir);
            System.out.print("Enter number of elements : ");
            String str = bf.readLine();
            int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
            stack testStack = new stack(num);
            int test =5;
            testStack.push(test);



        }

        public static void main(String[] args){

          stackStarter TEST = new stackStarter();

        }


    }
```

I keep getting the error...cannot find symbol - class stackStarter. I tried putting all of the code from the stackStarter method in the main, but I cannot access the stack class from the static main method...any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You should be instantiating the class not the method. Your `main` method should be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    stackTest test = new stackTest();
    test.stackStarter();

}
```

One more thing, you should follow the Java Naming Convention while writing your code. 
e.g. `stackTest` is not a valid class name according to Java naming standard, it should be `StackTest`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    stackTest TEST = new stackTest();
    TEST.stackStarter();
}
```

Comment: You should explain a little more what was wrong. Your answer is being flagged as low quality.

Comment: oh, i thought that it was just a silly mistake that you were not able to figure out. Your comment suggests that you are very new to java. (You should mention this in ur question). You must read this article about creating objects in java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html. Long story short: `new` must be followed by a class name and not a method name.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it shows exactly there are only two classes stack and stackTest , There is no classs called stackStarter ,Only method has defined in the stackTest, Change the constructor  stackStarter() to stackTest() in main() and invoke the method with object as follows it would compile and will work fine ,

```
public class stackTest
      {

       public void stackStarter(){

            System.out.println("Welcome to our Stack Simulator");
            InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(ir);
            System.out.print("Enter number of elements : ");
            String str = bf.readLine();
            int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
            stack testStack = new stack(num);
            int test =5;
            testStack.push(test);

        }

        public static void main(String[] args){

          stackTest TEST = new stackTest();
           TEST.stackStarter();    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public class stackTest
{

   static void stackStarter(){

        System.out.println("Welcome to our Stack Simulator");
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(ir);
        System.out.print("Enter number of elements : ");
        String str = bf.readLine();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
        stack testStack = new stack(num);
        int test =5;
        testStack.push(test);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
      stackStarter();
    }

}
```

The main "gotcha" is that you want stackStarter() to be a "method", not a "class".  So you simply call it (instead of "new").

The second "gotcha" is that "main()" is a static class.  So if you want to call stackStarter() from main(), then starckStarter() needs to be static, too.